# jquery Multiple text scroll on div hover not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have This Code for scroll text on hover div using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="target" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText1">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText1">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText1">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
```

JS:

```
$(function()
  {
   $(".tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
   "speed": 300,
   "loop": false,
   "target":'#target'
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
.tooMuchText {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: default;
}
```

So, I need to Scroll multiple(for each) div text on hover with `target` id. But My code Work only in first `div` with `target` id. how do can I fox this problem ?!

Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzhpbhcf/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one conceptual problem here:

- id's should always be unique - for identical items, use classes

There are obviously more elegant ways to do this, but latching onto your use of id's, you can expand that, and iterate through the spans, gather their unique ID, then grab the unique ID of the parent, using that as the target.

```
$(function() {
    $(".tooMuchText").each(function() {

    var thisParentId = $(this).parents("div").attr("id");
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#' + thisId).hoverForMore({
      "speed": 300,
      "loop": false,
      "target": '#' + thisParentId
    });

  });
});
```

To finish this up, just add a unique id to each of your SPANs and DIVs.

```
<div id="target3" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span id='tooMuchText3' class="tooMuchText">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just example can you try multiple class in div ? if yes than i have try this in js fiddle please check.. if it may help you

```js
(function($, window) {
  var isjQuery = !!$.fn.jquery;

  var isFirefox = /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  var isMobile = /Mobile/.test(navigator.userAgent);

  var defaults = {
    "speed": 60.0,
    "gap": 20,
    "loop": true,
    "removeTitle": true,
    "snapback": true,
    "alwaysOn": false,
    "addStyles": true,
    "target": true,
    "startEvent": isMobile ? "touchstart" : (isjQuery ? "mouseenter" : "mouseover"),
    "stopEvent": isMobile ? "touchend" : (isjQuery ? "mouseleave" : "mouseout")
  };


  $.fn['hoverForMore'] = function(options) {
    var self = this;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var originalOverflow, originalOverflowParent, startTime;

    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var targetSelector = options.target || self.selector;

    // Always-on without looping is just silly
    if (options.alwaysOn) {
      options.loop = true;
      options.startEvent = "startLooping"; // only triggered programmatically
    }

    // Detect CSS prefix and presence of CSS animation
    var hasAnimation = document.body.style.animationName ? true : false,
      animationString = 'animation',
      transitionString = 'transition',
      transformString = 'transform',
      keyframePrefix = '',
      domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz O ms Khtml'.split(' '),
      pfx = '';

    // Find the CSS prefix, if necessary
    if (hasAnimation === false)
      for (var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++) {
        if (document.body.style[domPrefixes[i] + 'AnimationName'] === undefined)
          continue;

        pfx = domPrefixes[i];
        animationString = pfx + 'Animation';
        transitionString = pfx + 'Transition';
        transformString = pfx + 'Transform';
        cssPrefix = '-' + pfx.toLowerCase() + '-';
        hasAnimation = true;
        break;
      }

    // Auto-add ellipsis and such
    if (options.addStyles) {
      head.appendChild($(
        '<style type="text/css">' + self.selector + '{' + 'cursor:default;' + 'text-align:left;' + 'display:block;' + 'overflow:hidden;' + 'white-space:nowrap;' + 'text-overflow:ellipsis;' + cssPrefix + 'user-select: none;' + '}</style>')[0]);
    }

    // Non-animation fallback. TODO: Animate with jQuery instead
    if (!hasAnimation) {
      // Fallback to title text hover
      $(options.target || self.selector).each(function(n, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        $el.attr("title", $.trim($el.text()));
      });
      return self;
    }

    // Keyframes are only used in loop mode
    if (options.loop) {
      // Attach global style
      var $keyframeStyle = $('<style type="text/css"></style>');
      var $keyframeStyleReverse = $('<style type="text/css"></style>');
      head.appendChild($keyframeStyle[0]);
      head.appendChild($keyframeStyleReverse[0]);
    }

    // For non-loop mode, set an empty transform value (FireFox needs this to transition properly)
    else {
      $(self.selector).each(function(n, el) {
        el.style[transformString] = 'translateX(0px)';
      });
    }


    // Attach start event
    $(targetSelector).on(options.startEvent, function(e) {
      startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

      // Get hovered item, and ensure that it contains an overflown item
      var $item = $(options.target ? self.selector : this).filter(":first");
      if (!$item.length) return true;

      var $parent = $item.parent();
      var pixelDiff = $item[0].scrollWidth - $item.width();

      if (pixelDiff <= 0) // && !options.alwaysOn // TODO: <marquee> without overflow
        return true;

      if (options.removeTitle) $item.removeAttr("title");

      // Over-ride the text overflow, and cache the overflow css that we started with
      originalOverflowParent = originalOverflowParent || $parent.css("overflow");
      originalOverflow = originalOverflow || $item.css("overflow");

      $parent.css("overflow", "hidden");
      if (isMobile && options.addStyles)
        $('body').css(cssPrefix + "user-select", "none");

      $item
        .css("overflow", "visible")
        .addClass("scrolling");

      if (options.loop) {
        // Remove a previous clone
        $item.children(".hoverForMoreContent").remove();

        // Attach a duplicate string which will allow content to appear wrapped
        var $contentClone = $('<span class="hoverForMoreContent" />')
          .css({
            "paddingLeft": parseInt(options.gap) + "px"
          })
          .text($item.text());

        $item.append($contentClone);
        var contentWidth = ($contentClone.width() + parseInt(options.gap));

        // Build keyframe string and attach to global style
        var keyframes = '@' + cssPrefix + 'keyframes hoverForMoreSlide { ' + 'from {' + cssPrefix + 'transform:translateX( 0 ) }' + 'to {' + cssPrefix + 'transform:translateX( -' + contentWidth + 'px ) }' + '}';
        $keyframeStyle[0].innerHTML = keyframes;

        // Go go gadget animation!
        var sec = contentWidth / parseFloat(options.speed);

        $item[0].style[animationString] = 'hoverForMoreSlide ' + sec + 's linear infinite';
      } else // if(!options.loop)
      {
        var sec = pixelDiff / parseFloat(options.speed);

        // Apply transition + transform instead of looping
        $item[0].style[transitionString] = cssPrefix + 'transform ' + sec + 's linear';

        // Alas, Firefox won't honor the transition immediately
        if (!isFirefox)
          $item[0].style[transformString] = 'translateX(-' + pixelDiff + 'px)';

        else setTimeout(function() {
          $item[0].style[transformString] = 'translateX(-' + pixelDiff + 'px)';
        }, 0);
      }
    });



    // Attach stop event
    if (!options.alwaysOn)
      $(targetSelector).on(options.stopEvent, function(e) {
        var $item = $(options.target ? self.selector : this).filter(":first");
        if (!$item.length) return true;

        if (options.loop) {
          if (options.snapback) {
            // Reverse our animation
            var contentWidth = $item.children('.hoverForMoreContent').width() + parseInt(options.gap);
            var timeDiff = ((new Date()).getTime() - startTime) * 0.001;
            var offsetX = (timeDiff * options.speed) % contentWidth;
            var switchDirection = offsetX > (contentWidth / 2);

            // Build keyframe string and attach to global style
            var keyframes = '@' + cssPrefix + 'keyframes hoverForMoreSlideReverse { ' + 'from {' + cssPrefix + 'transform:translateX( ' + (0 - offsetX) + 'px ) }' + 'to {' + cssPrefix + 'transform:translateX( ' + (switchDirection ? 0 - contentWidth : 0) + 'px ) }' + '}';
            $keyframeStyleReverse[0].innerHTML = keyframes;

            var sec = (switchDirection ? contentWidth - offsetX : offsetX) * 0.2 / parseFloat(options.speed);
            $item[0].style[animationString] = 'hoverForMoreSlideReverse ' + (sec > 1 ? 1 : sec) + 's linear';

            $item.removeClass("scrolling");

            // After animation resolves, restore original overflow setting, and remove the cloned element
            setTimeout(function() {
              if ($item.is(".scrolling")) return;

              $item
                .children(".hoverForMoreContent")
                .remove();

              $item.css("overflow", originalOverflow);
              $item.parent().css("overflow", originalOverflowParent);

              if (isMobile && options.addStyles)
                $('body').css(cssPrefix + "user-select", 'text');
            }, (sec * 1000) - -50);
          } else // if(!options.snapback)
          {
            $item[0].style[animationString] = '';

            $item
              .css("overflow", originalOverflow)
              .find(".hoverForMoreContent")
              .remove();

            $item.parent().css("overflow", originalOverflowParent);

            if (isMobile && options.addStyles)
              $('body').css(cssPrefix + "user-select", 'text');
          }
        } else // if(!options.loop)
        {
          var timeDiff = ((new Date()).getTime() - startTime) / 1000.0;
          var match = $item[0].style[transitionString].match(/transform (.*)s/);
          var sec = (match && match[1] && parseFloat(match[1]) < timeDiff) ? parseFloat(match[1]) : timeDiff;
          sec *= 0.5;

          if (!options.snapback)
            $item[0].style[transitionString] = '';
          else
            $item[0].style[transitionString] = cssPrefix + 'transform ' + sec + 's linear';

          $item.removeClass("scrolling")

          // Firefox needs a delay for the transition to take effect
          if (!isFirefox)
            $item[0].style[transformString] = 'translateX(0px)';

          else setTimeout(function() {
            $item[0].style[transformString] = 'translateX(0px)';
          }, 0);

          if (!options.snapback) {
            $item.css("overflow", originalOverflow);

            if (isMobile && options.addStyles)
              $('body').css(cssPrefix + "user-select", 'text');
          } else // if(options.snapback)
          {
            setTimeout(function() {
              if ($item.is(".scrolling")) return;
              $item.css("overflow", originalOverflow);

              if (isMobile && options.addStyles)
                $('body').css(cssPrefix + "user-select", 'text');
            }, sec * 1000);
          }
        }

      });


    // To manually refresh active elements when in always-on mode
    self.refresh = function() {
      $(self.selector).each(function(n, el) {
        $(el).not(".scrolling").trigger(options.startEvent);
      })
    };


    // Always-on mode, activate! <marquee>, eat your heart out.
    if (options.alwaysOn)
      self.refresh();

    return self;
  };

})(window.jQuery || $);



$(function() {
  
  $(".tooMuchText1").hoverForMore({
    "speed": 300,
    "loop": false,
    "target": '#target'
  });
  
   $(".tooMuchText2").hoverForMore({
    "speed": 300,
    "loop": false,
    "target": '#target1'
  });
  $(".tooMuchText3").hoverForMore({
    "speed": 300,
    "loop": false,
    "target": '#target2'
  });
});
```

```css
.tooMuchText {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText1">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target1" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText2">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="target2" style="width: 300px;height:100px; margin-left: 50px; background-color: #ddd;">

  <span class="tooMuchText tooMuchText3">Got too much text to fit in your content area? Just hover for more more more more more more!</span>
</div>
<br>
```